# How to use createTextNode() by concatenation

Tags: javascript, dom, text, special-characters, sanitization

I need to process some text through CreateTextNode, as it may contain special characters.

I'm wondering what would be the equivalent of:

```
/* var status holds some text */  

contentStatus = document.createTextNode(status);

 content = '<div id="user">' + name +'</div><div id="stat">' + contentStatus + '</div>';
```

Right now, `contentStatus` is simply showing up as `[object Text]` when `content` is inserted into the DOM.

Everywhere I look, `appendChild` is used with `CreateTextNode`. How can I achieve the equivalent of above, which I assume is not valid?

Comment: why can't you just put the text from `status` in the concatenation?

Comment: you are parsing the `content` as a string, might as well skip the `contentStatus` assignment and put `status` directly in the concat string `content`.

Comment: I was referred to CreateTextNode() in my search for a way to sanitize my string input into the DOM. Basically I'm trying to prevent users from entering `<div class="someclass"> sometext </div>" or equivalent. As currently, the class and div would be rendered and would not show up as actual text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `textContent` property:

```
 content = '<div id="user">' + name+'</div>'
 +'<div id="stat">' 
 + contentStatus.data//This takes the actual string
 + '</div>';
```

but there is a better way:

```
var user = document.createElement('div');
curName = document.createTextNode(name);
user.appendChild(name);
user.id = "user";
var stat = document.createElement('div');
stat.id = "stat";
contentStatus = document.createTextNode(status);
stat.appendChild(contentStatus);
user.appendChild(stat);
console.log(user);//    <div id=​"user">​…​</div>​
```

This way is better because you dealing with dom elements and you can now manipulate them as such.

Comment: ahh, thank you! The first method was quick and worked. The second method is neat! I will try it out.

Comment: @Gnuey happy i can help. I have experienced the second method introduces less errors later on.

Comment: Ah alright, I will definitely take heed of this in my future coding projects then. Thanks again for the referral to this method.

Comment: If `contentStatus` is definitely a text node, either of its `data` or `nodeValue` properties will work and be compatible in more browsers than `textContent`, which is not supported in IE <= 8.

Comment: @TimDown nice tip. Updated.